# SQL Rank while keeping time sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dense-rank

Given this data

```
Type    Time    Outcome Wanted Result
1   8:00    1   1
1   9:00    1   1
1   10:00   1   1
0   11:00   2   2
0   12:00   2   2
0   13:00   2   2
1   14:00   1   3
1   15:00   1   3
0   16:00   2   4
1   17:00   1   5
0   18:00   2   6
1   19:00   1   7
```

The third column is the current result I have using the following sql query:

```
SELECT Type, Time, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Type) as Outcome
FROM Tbl
```

I need the dense_rank to keep the time sorted while ranking the data by type. The 4th column is the wanted result.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky.  You can do this with a difference of row numbers.  This method is a little difficult to understand at first, so I recommend that you run the subqueries to understand what is happening.  You'll quickly "get it" when you look at the results:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by mintime) as desired_column
from (select t.*,
             min(time) over (partition by id, seqnum_t - seqnum_it) as mintime
      from (select t.*, 
                   row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum_t,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by time) as seqnum_it
            from tbl t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff ! I just changed the
`min(time) over (partition by seqnum_t - seqnum_it) as mintime`
to
`min(time) over (partition by seqnum_t - seqnum_it,id) as mintime`